# I'm having problems connecting microservices with eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to connect my service to eureka server, but it seems that eureka does not recognize it.

I want eureka to recognize the services.

When I go to http://localhost:8761/ it works and the same for microservice.

Eureka server properties:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.renewalPercentThreshold=0.85
```

Eureka application:

```java
package com.example.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaserverApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Pom dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

MICROSERVICE:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agency_microservice
spring.datasource.username = password
spring.datasource.password = password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
server.port=8082

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.application.name=businessdomain-agency
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
package com.agency.agency;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AgencyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgencyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. It seems all perfect, maybe the problem could be the version of eureka that I'm using.